# How come changing the speed of an animation isnt making the animation speed up?

Tags: unity, animation

I made an animation of a bow string being pulled and another animation of the string being released but my issue is that I need the string to snap back quickly. I changed the speed of the release animation which is what makes the string go back to being straight (as if you had just released it). However, changing the speed isn't making the animation happen any faster... Any ideas why this might be happening?

[image: Just to show u I'm not an idiot and I'm changing the speed in the right spot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out unity's transitions were the issue. I had the transition set too slow so no matter how fast I made my animation, it would still take the whole length of the transition for the string to snap back. The way to solve this; decrease the transition time!

Answer (score 0):

that doesnt work in **Animator**.

for working with animator you have to use like this:

```
 float CurrentSpeed = m_Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).speed;
```

if you are in first layer, use zero index else use other indexes.